# Trying to find smallest array elements from 2 arrays returns 0 (doesn't work) and the other works. (C lang)

Tags: arrays, c, numbers, element

I'm trying to accomplish a simple task in C which is to print out the smallest number from array 1 and smallest number from array 2. Both array elements are imputed by the user.

First one just returns 0 (which in my testing case its supposed to be 1) and the other one returns the correct one (11). I seriously can't understand why and I also tried to google this with no result so that's when I once again decided to seek help here!

```
int main () {

    int masyvas1[10] = {0};
    int masyvas2[10] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        int x;
        printf("Ivesk pirmo masyvo 10 sk: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        masyvas1[i] = x;

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        int x;
        printf("Ivesk antro masyvo 10 sk: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        masyvas2[i] = x;

    }

    int mas1maz[2] = {0, 0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        if(masyvas1[i] < mas1maz[1]){

            mas1maz[1] = masyvas1[i];

        }

        if(masyvas2[i] < mas1maz[2]){

            mas1maz[2] = masyvas2[i];

        }

    }

    printf("testas: %d %d", mas1maz[1], mas1maz[2]);

}
```

If I enter numbers say from 1 to 10 for the first array and 11 to 20 for the second the program output is: `testas: 0 11` which I was expecting it to be `testas: 1 11`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like you to go over your program by trying what is below

```
int mas1maz[2] = {0, 0};
```

The Array has 2 elements, try to print each element.
**Note:** there are only 2 elements but I am printing 3 as you have used  `mas1maz[2]` ( this is grabage= 11)

```
printf("%d,%d,%d",mas1maz[0],mas1maz[1],mas1maz[2]);
```

Then you are trying to compare with `mas1maz[1]=0`, this will result in a minimum always equal to zero.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    /*
     */
    if(masyvas1[i] < mas1maz[1]) {
        mas1maz[1] = masyvas1[i];
    }
```

Here you are tyring to compare  `mas1maz[2]` with `garbage=11`, this is the reason why you see 11.

```
    if(masyvas2[i] < mas1maz[2]) {
        mas1maz[2] = masyvas2[i];
    }
```

What you should try is the following :

```
for(int i = 0; i<9; i++) {
    if(masyvas1[i]>masyvas1[i+1])
    {
       /*copy to your array*/  
        mas1maz[0]=masyvas1[i]
    }
    /* similarly for masyvas2*/
}
```

see that for an array of length `len`, indices of the array ranges from `0` to `len-1`

Comment: Alright thanks to your first comment on my code I got it (sometimes for me an array of [10] has 10 elements and sometimes its actually 11 it depends and in this case here its 11 ether it's this or that I still don't catch up...). All I hade to do when storing 2 values in an array is to change `int mas1maz[2] = {0, 0};` to `int mas1maz[1] = {0, 0};` and the end result is finally `testas: 1 11` (1-20 are the values I was entering when running the program to test). That's all I had to change for it to work. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(masyvas2[i] < masyvas2[i]){

        mas1maz[2] = masyvas2[i];

    }
```

Change your second if as follow. You was checking for smaller number in masmaz1 array and was passing 2 in array parameters which is not compatible. As you have initialized an array for 2 locations 0 and 1 as array locations are started from 0. So change that Second if to compare it with itself for smallest number.

Comment: I somehow don't think that would work especially when the problem is with the first 'if'. I did try it though and the program returned `testas: 0 0` now.

Comment: And you can follow this to correct your first array.

Comment: if(masyvas1[i] < masyvas1[i]){

        mas1maz[1] = masyvas1[i];

    }

Comment: Here you have issue with your array locations, you have given 2 where you have only [0 and 1] location in masmaz1[2]. by correcting this , i am pretty sure that you could have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
int min;
int max;
int i;

min=max=mas1maz[0];

    for(i=1; i<10; i++)
    {
         if(min>mas1maz[i])
          min=mas1maz[i];       
    }
```

You should use this after you fill your tables with scanf to find the minimum value

then compare the two different minimums

Comment: 'mas1maz' is actually the 'min' value only instead of two 'int' I write it as an array with 2 elements. Its a homework assignment and I'm supposed to make the program to write 'masyvas1' array smallest element to 'mas1maz[1]' and 'masyvas2' array smallest element to 'mas1maz[2]'